# am using mongodb aggregation which am expecting different output but am not getting the desired out put

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

actually  want output as `RSPI:348` but am getting as below .can any one please help me .

```
 have used below query.am using mongo db aggregations where i want to group by scac(whose value is dqFact) and count how many orders got delayed for particular scac so i did as below.can any one please correct me
```

```js
aggregate([
    { 
      '$match' : { 
        'salesOrder.shipDate' : { 
           '$gte' : '2021-03-18T00:00:00', 
           '$lte' : '2021-03-18T23:59:59'
         }
       }
    },
    { "$match": { "dqCategory" : "shipmentdata" } },
    { "$match": { "dqState" : "fail" } },
    { "$match": { "salesOrder.region" : "US" } },
    { 
      "$group" : {
        "_id": {
          "scac": "$dqFact",
          "shipDelay": "$dqMeasure.shippeddelay"
        }
      }
    },
    { 
      "$project": { 
        "_id": 0,
        "dqMeasure.shippeddelay": 1,
        "dqFact":1
       } 
    }
])
```

and out put to the above query is

```js
    
    {
        "_id" : {
            "scac" : "RPSI",
            "shipDelay" : "31"
        }
    }
    
    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : {
            "scac" : "RPSI",
            "shipDelay" : "317"
        }
    }
```

actually the query i used is not giving the result i want. i need count of shippeddelay for
a specific scac. here one of the scac is RSPI as shown below.
{
"_id" : {
RSPI:348
}
}

## the document structure is

"event" : {
"eventId" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"eventTimestamp" : "2021-05-27 10:12:50"
},
"salesOrder" : {
"orderNum" : "1111111111",
"buid" : "xx",
"orderStatus" : "xx",
"statusCode" : "xx",
"orderDate" : "2021-05-27 10:01:42.000",
"shipDate" : "2021-03-23T02:54:18",
"region" : "xx",
"cotStatus" : "XX",
"companyNum" : "XX",
"LOB" : "PowerEdge",
"orderType" : "XX",
"orderTypeCategory" : "XX",
"shipToCountryCode" : "XX",
"itemNum" : "XX",
"itemDesc" : "XX",
"orderSource" : "XX",
"classificationCode" : "SYSTEM",
"poNumber" : "XXXX",
"shippingCode" : "8"

Comment: Can you add an example of the document, and the expected result?

Comment: Hello Nenad thank you for the response.

Comment: Hello Nenad i have edited and added the document structure.please go through it and help me to resolve it